# SWT WizardDialog not showing in TaskBar

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am creating a `WizardDialog` as follows in a command line application

```java
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
Wizard wiz = new ImportWizard();
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, wiz);
dialog.create();
dialog.open();
```

The wizard dialog does show. But it does not show up in Taskbar.
I also tried

```java
shell.setVisible(true);
dialog.open();
```

This got the Shell to show up in the taskbar, but the shell window was visible behind the wizard.

How I can resolve this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Doesn't the wizard show up at all or does it just not have its own icon in the start-/task-bar?

Comment: The wizard does show up, but it has now icon in the task bar.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using the following snippet

```java
Wizard wiz = new ImportWizard();
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(null, wiz);
dialog.create();
dialog.open();
```

By passing `null` as `Shell` in the `WizardDialog` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I might assume, that the reason for such behavior is that `WizardDialog` class has only constructor to provide `Shell`, which in the end (in `Dialog` class) uses `SameShellProvider` as a shell provider. You need to inherit from something, where you can pass your own `IShellProvider`, for instance `TrayDialog` (or some other suitable class).